# How can loop be rewritten as anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, loops, reduce

how can this type of loop be overwritten

```js
let num - fieldOffset[0];
for (let i = 1; i < fieldOffset.length; i++) {
          if (fieldOffset[i] < fieldOffset[i - 1]) {
            num += fieldOffset[i];
          }
        }
```

as an anonymous function of the following type:

```js
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
array1.reduce(reducer)
```

Comment: "overwritten" => "rewritten"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the third (optional) argument of Array.prototype.reduce should do the trick:

```
num = fieldOffset.reduce((acc, value, index) => acc += (index && (value > fieldOffset[index - 1])) ? value : 0, 0);
```

Comment: friend, now check, I added one value "num". I need to sum up all the values in the array that fit the conditions. How do I write this?

Comment: My line does what your code did before the edit, your edit is now syntactically wrong, if you wanted num to start with first array item value, just do it: num = fieldOffset[0] + fieldOffset.reduce(...